# How to know if User disabled transparency in Settings -> Accessibility?

Tags: ios, widget, ios8, transparency, ios-app-extension

I'm working on a Widget / Today View extension and I'd like to adapt the design if user disabled transparency effect in Settings -> General -> Accessibility.

Indeed, in case the user disabled transparency, the overall appearance of the notification center is so different that my default design is ugly.

Do you know how to retrieve this settings in order to react accordingly?

Comment: Which one Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> ??????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an accessibility setting to reduce transparency but I'm not aware of one to completely disable it. If the former is what you mean then starting in iOS8 you should be able to use:

```
BOOL UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()
```

You can also register for changes to this setting using the following notification name:

```
UIAccessibilityReduceTransparencyStatusDidChangeNotification
```